# Problema al subir post django

Tags: python, django, reactjs

Estoy con una app creada en **React** y backend en **Python**, pasando con la parte del CRUD al momento de editar un post que esta guardado en la base a traves de una peticion todo bien. el problema surge al momento de crear un nuevo post. Al crear un post a traves del front con su respectivo metodo POST me aparece el siguiente error dentro de la respuesta 500.

> IntegrityError at /api/ NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_article.author_id

Aun no logro establecer que podria estar pasando dentro de la api o quizas estoy enviando mal los datos a traves del fetch. Adjunto mi modelo de la bd:

```
class Article(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
content = models.TextField(blank=True)
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
default='', blank=True, null=True)
url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Category(models.Model):
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.category_name
```

desde el front envio la data desde la pagina create.js de la siguiente manera una vez capturados los datos en el formulario:

```
export class CreatePost extends React.Component {

state = {
    newPost: []
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let newObj = { [name]: value };
    const newData = {...this.state.newPost, ...newObj};
    this.setState({
        newPost: newData
    })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('posted ', this.state.newPost);
    const secretKey = localStorage.getItem('key');
    let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newPost),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `token ${secretKey}`
        }
    })
    .then(resp => {
        console.log('respuesta de la subida ', resp.status);
        return resp.text();
    })
}



render() {
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <h1>Create page</h1>
            <form>
                <input name='title' placeholder='title' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <input name='description' placeholder='description' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <input name='content' placeholder='content' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <input name='category' placeholder='category' onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                <button onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>Crea</button>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Si lo has solucionado, en la parte inferior de esta página hay un espacio que dice "Tu Respuesta", agrega lo que has realizado, y en 24 horas marca la respuesta como aceptada para ayudar a mantener la buena salud del sitio y colaborar con más desarrolladores :D

Comment: gracias amigo :D

Answer (score 3):

Dentro del modelo, en el campo **Author** debía poner `null=true`

```
class Article(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
content = models.TextField(blank=True)
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
default='', blank=True, null=True)
url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```